# PHP/MySQL - preparing string in a right format for inserting in a datetime SQL column

Tags: php, sql

In my UI the dates are shown like this - `dd.mm.YYYY hh:ii:ss`. The users are able to edit/add new dates and most probably they'll try to use the same format (24.06.2012 15:35:00) which can not be used for a SQL query. Here is what I've done till now:

```
$dt = (date_parse_from_format("d.m.Y H:i:s", $data['event_time']));
        $newdate = sprintf("%02d-%02d-%04d %02d:%02d:%02d" , $dt['day'], $dt['month'], $dt['year'], $dt['hour'], $dt['minute'], $dt['second']);
        $test = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($newdate));
        if ($test == "1970-01-01 01:00:00")
        {
            throw new Exception('Invalid date');
        }
```

What happens is - if I leave the check `if ($test == "1970-01-01 01:00:00")` I get an exception, but if I comment the `$test = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($newdate));` line and the check the date is inserted only with zeros.
  `$newdate` is a sting in the right format for SQL - `YYYY-mm-dd H:i:s` but obv. I miss something here. How to insert this string as a valid SQL datetime?

Thanks

Leron

Comment: Sorry, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" was for .Net. For PHP, "Y-m-d H:i:s" is correct. try to print out strtotime(#newdate) and see the value.

Comment: where are you inserting the date? try to print the date at each step to make sure about your observations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class was introduced in PHP 5.2 and would allow you to use something like this

```
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat("d.m.Y H:i:s", $data['event_time']);
if($dt === false){
  throw new Exception("Invalid date");
}
```

[DateTime::createFromFormat](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) returns false on failure (This method is only available since PHP 5.3)

Then when saving to the database you can use the following to get the correct format for MySQL

```
$dt->format("Y-m-d H:i:s")
```

Comment: Sorry, it's me being not that good in OOP but I try `$dt =  DateTime::createFromFormat("d.m.Y H:i:s", $data['event_time']);` and then directly insert `$dt` into my DB and it returns this error : `Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string` where could be the problem?

Comment: replace `$dt` with `$dt->format("Y-m-d H:i:s")` in your query. the format method returns a string version of the date in the format passed as a parameter

Comment: And yse I use `$dt->format..` but then I get no error and no new record.

Comment: Can you update the question to include the section of code that is running the insert query?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, first time maybe It was a typo now it works fine. Thanks for help. Your solution is exactly what I needed. Thanks.

Comment: Great stuff, glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

MySQL provides the FROM_UNIXTIME( ) and UNIX_TIMESTAMP( ) functions to convert a Unix timestamp to a MySQL date format, and vice versa.

```
$SqlString = "INSERT INTO table(mydate, content) VALUES (FROM_UNIXTIME($mydate), $content)";
```

UNIX_TIMESTAMP, if called with no argument, returns a Unix timestamp (seconds since '1970-01-01 00:00:00' UTC) as an unsigned integer. If UNIX_TIMESTAMP() is called with a date argument, it returns the value of the argument as seconds since '1970-01-01 00:00:00' UTC. date may be a DATE string, a DATETIME string, a TIMESTAMP, or a number in the
format YYMMDD or YYYYMMDD.

```
$SqlString = "SELECT *, UNIX_TIMESTAMP($mydate) AS mydate FROM table WHERE conId = $conId";
```

Take a deeper look at these MySql functions and also the mktime() function could help you.